# How can we get analog input in Raspberry Pi from a Hall Effect Sensor?

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, sensors, raspberry-pi2, arduino-uno

I am trying to connect my hall effect sensor to Raspberry Pi to get the raw analog data. I've been able to do that in Arduino UNO by  connecting it to the analog pin and using AnalogRead, but I can't find its equivalent in RPI. All the sample programs in the internet only let me find boolean result.

I'm a total beginner in using these things, so I might have been missing a very simple point. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you post your sensor model? Hall sensors ouput a voltage proportional to the field, so just reading it with the RPi ADC port should be enough.

Comment: It's a3144. I'm planning to use it around electric wires to determine whether a machine is in use or not based on the magnetic field created around the wire.

Comment: This is a hall effect switch, not a sensor. So you'll only have on/off results. Also, what's the current on the cable? If I did my math right you'll need placing that sensor at 10mm of a cable with >500mA to turn that switch.

Comment: Oh no! Then I might have to get something else. What should be the distance to place it for around 12A current? Also, how do you think it'd respond to AC? thanks.

Comment: Depends on the distance. [Here is the field of a wire formula](https://www.pa.msu.edu/courses/1997spring/PHY232/lectures/ampereslaw/wire.html).  You'll need to buy a sensor with a lower threshold (Datasheet's are usually in Gauss and the formula is in Tesla). You may also sense AC current with a wire clamp via transformer effect. A hall effect also works, but will produce a switching signal.

Answer (score 0):

### Raspberry Pi IO

The raspberry pi I/O does not include an analog reading, so at the simplest level, this is not possible.

### In conjunction with arduino

If you don't mind keeping your arduino, then you can run your arduino to get a variable value from a hall-effect sensor, and then transmit that analog signal over `SPI` or `I2C` to the raspberry pi - that can just read the values directly.  This [github project](https://github.com/ThatPerson/ElderNet/tree/master/pi_thermometer) uses i2c to transmit a temperature reading from an Arduino to the raspberry pi, and then to a php server.